# How draw plane in three js with two diagonal position vectors known?

Tags: graphics, three.js

We can add plane geometry with this code and position in anywhere:

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 5, 20, 32 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00, side: THREE.DoubleSide} );
var plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( plane );
```

But how can we add plane when two diagonal positions are known. Is this possible?

[image: Draw plane geometry with diagonal positions known]

The closest to this so far I have is to get center of two positions and it positions the plane correctly but does not size correctly:

```
var dir = pointB.clone().subtract(pointA);
var length = dir.length();
dir = dir.normalize().scale(length * 50);
center_position = pointA.clone().add(dir);
```

*Direction is not important in my case, can be set by lookat().*

Answer (score 2):

Find the subtraction vector of those two, its absolute values are plane size.
Average vector of those two is plane's center.

Example (r120):

```js
let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 100);
camera.position.set(0, 5, 10);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

let controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper());

let vec1 = new THREE.Vector3(0, 2, 0);
let vec2 = new THREE.Vector3(4, 0, 0);

let size = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(vec2, vec1);
let center = new THREE.Vector3().addVectors(vec1, vec2).multiplyScalar(0.5);

let planeWidth = Math.abs(size.x);
let planeHeight = Math.abs(size.y);
let planeGeom = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(planeWidth, planeHeight, planeWidth, planeHeight);
let planeMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "aqua",
  wireframe: true
});
let plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeom, planeMat);
plane.position.copy(center);
scene.add(plane);

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.122.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.122.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `let planeBreadth = Math.abs(size.z); if(planeWidth < planeBreadth && planeWidth < planeHeight){ planeWidth = planeBreadth; } else if(planeHeight < planeBreadth && planeHeight < planeWidth){planeHeight = planeBreadth;}` Added this code still not working correctly, is this modification in right direction?.